# Remove properties from JSON object not present in schema?

Tags: python, json, jsonschema

I am using Python's [jsonschema](https://github.com/Julian/jsonschema) to validate JSON files against a schema. It works great. But now I need to remove any properties from my JSON that are not present in the schema.

I know that according to [the JSON Schema docs](http://json-schema.org/), I can set the property:

```
additionalProperties = false
```

to reject any files with additional properties. But this will just *reject* the properties, not actually *remove* them.

What is the best way to remove them?

I guess I can write my own script that:

- walks every leaf node of the JSON file
- checks whether the leaf node exists in the schema
- if it does not, walks up the tree until it finds the highest node that does exist, then prunes the branch at that point.

My question is: is there an existing Python library to do this, or do I need to write one? I have Googled, but without any success.

Comment: Did you solve this? I have same situation with c#.

Comment: I'm also interested in this use case and opened a [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/Julian/jsonschema/issues/448).

Comment: got the same issue in ruby : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60569726/how-to-remove-in-a-hash-the-properties-that-do-not-exists-in-its-json-schema

Answer (score 3):

You could extend the validator. A similar [implementation is used for default values](https://python-jsonschema.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq/#why-doesn-t-my-schema-s-default-property-set-the-default-on-my-instance).

A little bit late, but here is a solution.

I extend the validator to override validation of `properties` keyword. If one of properties exists in instance but not in the schema, I remove it from the instance.

```py
from jsonschema import Draft7Validator, validators

def extend_validator(validator_class):
    validate_properties = validator_class.VALIDATORS["properties"]

    def remove_additional_properties(validator, properties, instance, schema):
        for prop in list(instance.keys()):
            if prop not in properties:
                del instance[prop]

        for error in validate_properties(
            validator, properties, instance, schema,
        ):
            yield error

    return validators.extend(
        validator_class, {"properties" : remove_additional_properties},
    )

DefaultValidatingDraft7Validator = extend_validator(Draft7Validator)

# Example usage:
obj = {
    'foo': 'bar',
    'not_in_schema': 'no no no'
}
schema = {
    'properties': {
        'foo': {
            'type': 'string'
        }
    }
}

DefaultValidatingDraft7Validator(schema).validate(obj)
assert obj == {'foo': 'bar'}
```

Comment: @Richard does it fix your issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a straight-forward way to achieve this without monkey patching the *iter_errors()* method in the *Validator* class:

https://github.com/Julian/jsonschema/blob/master/jsonschema/validators.py#L296